# does vscode inline breakpoint support C&C++ languange?

Tags: c, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (/*1*/ int i = 0; /*2*/i < 10 ; /*3*/i++) { /*4*/printf("hello\n");}
    return 0;
}
```

it seems vscode couldn't stop on breakpoint(in comments) in for statments

Comment: I don't think debuggers usually support this. And tbh, I don't really see the point either.

Comment: Added one breakpoint in your codeblock to better correspond to the image

Comment: @klutt, here is a demo on youtube, which works for js. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzYKDfTMCtg

Comment: @tarikjhin if it is another language. In gcc C it is almost impossible as debug info does not contain the inside loop information. So it is not possible using the gcc/gdb. Other compilers may add this info (I belive that ms one does it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a feature commonly supported. And TBH, I'd say it's a code smell if you have a need for it. Your example is trivial, and there it's no need to know what's going on between 2 and 3. And whenever you actually DO have a need for it, then your conditions and statements in the for header are likely too complicated.

And besides, most of the breakpoints. can be easily moved to equivalent positions.

```
/*1*/
/*2*/ First time
for (/*1*/ int i = 0; /*2*/i < 10 ; /*3*/i++) 
{ 
    /*4*/ printf("hello\n");
    /*2*/ Second time and later
}
```

But it's not possible to put a break between 2 and 3 without rewriting the code.

If you REALLY want this and your debugger don't support it, you can rewrite it in the following way. Change this:

```
for (<init>;<cond>;<inc>) 
{ 
    // Loop body
}
```

to this:

```
/*1*/
for (<init>;;) 
{ 
    /*2*/ if(!(<cond>)) break;

    /*4*/ // Loop body

    /*3*/ <inc>;
}
```

##### From comments:

> thanks, I know that the snippets post in description is of bad coding style, mainly reason behind this question is that I couldn't format existed code and I need to debug this code of bad coding style...

I completely understand your problem, but before debugging, it's often a very good advice to try to *refactor* the code to debuggable code before starting to debug.

##### Comparing to JS

You mentioned that you were able to do this in javascript. One good thing to remember here is that javascript is an interpreted language, while C and C++ are compiled languages. The compiled code does not necessarily have a good 1 to 1 correspondence with the source code. The debugger tries it best to do a good mapping, but it may fail. Especially with heavy optimization activated.

Comment: thanks, I know that the snippets post in description is of bad coding style, mainly reason behind this question is that I couldn't format existed code and I need to debug this code of bad coding style...

Comment: @tarikjhin Btw. If you're not allowed to format the existing code, how are you supposed to debug it? You have to modify the code to fix bugs.

Comment: I agree with your point about difference between compiled and interpreter languages, support for the inline breakpoint for js may depend on interpretation characteristic of dynamic language , remain to be confirmed.